# Test Sidekiq job that changes value of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I have the following controller:

```
def create
 @order = Order.create(order_params)
 OrderProcessorWorker.perform_async(@order.id)
end
```

And the following worker:

```
def perform(order_id)
  #.. some logic
  @order.status = 'processed'
  @order.save

  #.. some other logic
end
```

My question is... What is the correct way of testing that the job is changing the status of the Order? This gem https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq helps with testing that the job enqueued, delayed, retried...etc. But how do you test what is the job is actually doing?

EDIT: Here is what I have done:

```
describe OrderProcessorWorker do
  describe '#perform' do
    context 'an order without any pages' do
      it 'changes the status of the order to missing_pages' do
        FactoryGirl.create(:order_processing_status)
        p OrderProcessingStatus.all # => This shows the just created order_processing_status
        order = FactoryGirl.create(:order)
        subject.perform(order.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What happens is that, the perform method that is being called is not the one defined. I have tried doing `p 'hello worlds'` and it does not show in there.

Comment: You should only test `perform` method, and a fact that method `OrderProcessorWorker.perform_async` called with your id. Other stuff has already tested, because it's gem functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test that your worker is doing the work you intend it to do - test `perform` rather than `perform_async`:

```
describe OrderProcessorWorker do

  it 'changes order status' do
    subject.perform(order_id)

    expect(Order.find(id: order_id).status).to eq 'processed'
  end
end
```

Comment: But then when I am testing the create method, should I stub this: ``OrderProcessorWorker.perform_async(@order.id)`` In other words, if you are doing a full functional test, how do you deal with async jobs? ?

Comment: Or better still - `expect(OrderProcessorWorker).to receive(:perform_async).with((@order.id)`

Comment: What does that mean? Where would I put that expectation? When testing the create method?

Comment: Yes - it would fail the test if `perform_async` is not called (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message)

Comment: But ideally I would need to mock that call right? Because I am testing the create method, not the worker itself.

Comment: Yes, `expect` also mocks, it doesn't pass the call unless specifically asked to.

Comment: Actually, after doing the tests, I notice that I can't test the perform action per say. See my edit.

Comment: I think you don't want to use subject, but you need to create an instance for that worker. ``worker = OrderProcessorWorker.new ; worker.perform(...)``

Comment: That's it! However, I see that even if I change an attribute of the order, is not reflected outside of the perform. Why can that be?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing `create`:

```
assert_equal 0, OrderProcessorWorker.jobs.size
post :create, ...
assert_equal 1, OrderProcessorWorker.jobs.size
```